# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:[name="LinkLink[1]"]

Tags: jquery

После обновления версии jquery с 1.3.2 к 3.2.1 при исполнении следующего кода появляется ошибка:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   input:[name="LinkLink[1]"]

Не могу понять в чем загвоздка.

```
var getSize = function(nameInputLink, nameSizeLink){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: location.href,
        dataType: 'html',
        global: false,
        data: ({action : 'getsize', url: jQuery('input:[name="'+nameInputLink+'"]').val()}),
        success : function(data) {
            if(data != ''){
                jQuery('input:[name="'+nameSizeLink+'"]').val(data +' MB');
            }else{
                alert('Невозможно получить размер. Проверьте ссылку');
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Двоеточие убрать?

Comment: Где? После input?

Comment: Ага . . . . . .

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде сработало )